# Can a contiguous allocation boundary be forced in a C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, memory, boundary

Simple example:

```
template <class P> class MyT
{
    struct Item
    {
    public:
        Item() {}
        P *pData;
        Item *next;
    };
    Item *head;
public:
    ...adding etc..
    P* operator [](int index)
    {
       See question below:
    }
};
```

Can I somehow make sure that the 'Item's are allocated in such a way that I can calculate the offset as follows: (@Steve:) Maybe not so clear here; what I need is a quick & easy way to get to the item without iterating through 10000 next's.

```
Item *pi = head + (sizeof(Item) * (index - 1));
```

A [(clearer?) explanation](http://www.chineselinuxuniversity.net/articles/37130.shtml) of what I mean

Comment: This is weird. I suggest to use [] or next() - Not both. You also would have to make sure the array is allocated in one big piece, despite the arbitrary pointer *next suggests. You might want to look at QList instead (which is a linked list with indizes afaik. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qlist.html look at the source)

Comment: Do you have any specific reasons for not using standard library containers?

Comment: @Ronny: This is just a very simplified example to illustrate what I need to know: if there is a standard way of forcing memory boundaries I can use, instead of having to do my own buffer maintenance.

Comment: @Georg: I am using the STD stuff currently; I'm processing a large amount of data & need to optimize - this option is one of the possibilities I'm looking at.

Comment: I doubt that you actually mean `+ sizeof(Item) * (index - 1)`, since `head` is already of type `Item*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "etc", in "adding, etc".

If "etc" includes, "removing", then you have the obvious problem that if you remove something in the middle of your list, then to maintain the indexing you have to shift everything after it downwards, which means updating all the `next` pointers.

I think perhaps you have simplified your example too far. If you require contiguous storage, use a vector (either of `P`, or of `Item` if there's something useful in `Item` that you've removed). If you have contiguous storage, then there's no benefit in having a `next` pointer, since you could just calculate it in `Item`, by adding 1 to `this` (then checking a bound to make sure you haven't reached the end).

If you absolutely need the public `next` pointer field, because it's part of some interface you're implementing that you can't change, then you could update it in the copy constructor and `operator=` for `Item`, and the interface had better forbid clients from writing to it.

There's no way to tell the memory allocator to allocate contiguous storage for separate allocations, if that's what you're asking. How would that even work? What if when you come to allocate, the "next" address is already occupied? What if the allocator imposes some overhead, for its own control structures (as almost all general-purpose allocators do), so that allocating an `Item` requires more than `sizeof(Item)` bytes? You can get the behaviour you want for a while with a [fixed-size allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool), but eventually it needs a new block, or you delete something, and the relationship no longer holds.

Comment: Delete would be very rare (in my case) I would like to make retrieving as fast as possible. (See my edit changes for maybe a better explanation)

Comment: @slashmais: if performance of delete- and insert-at-middle aren't important, then use a vector instead of a linked list. If you need approximately the characteristics of a linked list, but you want faster lookups by index, you could try a skip list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list.

Comment: I did not know about Skip-lists - this looks very promising. In one of my attempts at optimizing I've implemented something approximately almost nearly similar to it :), but as usual, doubt crept in & I started looking for more conventional techniques, since I will eventually (soon) open-source the project. It is an attempt to achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/145489/15161 - after about three years of battling doubt & despondency. (You will not believe where investigating this project took me)

Comment: @slashmais: yes, it's always nice to have an algorithm that someone smart has proven correct, and published a peer-reviewed paper on, rather than something I invented that appears to work on the back of an envelope :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is a std::list or std::vector.

However what you are trying would work if you have allocated sequential memory for Items and head is pointing to the start along with the modification suggested by Yossarian.

You can pre-allocate while initializing if this limit is crossed, allocate more and copy your contents to that area, freeing the existing.

Note: All these things are wrapped for you in the std containers.

Answer (score 1):

"Memory Boundaries"  can be forced through special gcc keywords

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes

look at "alignment"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you need to override `operator new` for `Item` and have the allocator pre-allocate enough memory to store all the `Item`s you will ever need (which isn't possible in the general case but may be possible in your specific scenario). Then whenever an `Item` is newed up the allocator will return the next slot in the pre-allocated block.

All this looks un-realistic and the simple solution would be to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score -2):

```
Item* pi = (head + (index - 1));
```

does the job. Btw, are you sure you want to do this? `struct Item` looks like linked-list structure (contains `next`).

Comment: works only if it is allocated in one sweep ... the structure doesnt suggest this, though